# Xamarin UWP seems to bind to the wrong view model

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

I have a Xamarin project for Android and UWP. This issue seems to only happen on UWP.

In my Xamarin project I have `ContentPage` with a view model bound as context. In this ViewModel there's an `ObservableCollection` with another kind of view model. When I create a new instance of this underlying ViewModel and add to my ObservableCollection, sometimes the `ContentPage` works as expected, showing an item in my ListView. But sometimes there's an empty element added, that I can see when hovering over the list. When this happens I get a bunch of warnings in the Output tab.

My `DownloadsPage`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Downloader.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Downloader.Views.DownloadsPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DownloadStatusToColorConverter x:Key="downloadStatusToColor" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}">
        <ListView x:Name="DownloadsListView" SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Downloads}" RowHeight="70">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding DownloadStatus, Converter={StaticResource downloadStatusToColor}}">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   d:Text="{Binding .}"
                                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                                   FontSize="16" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0,10,0">
                                <ProgressBar BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Progress="{Binding PercentDownloaded}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="20">
                                </ProgressBar>
                                <Label Text="{Binding PercentString}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RefreshView>

</ContentPage>
```

`DownloadsViewModel` is set as context in the code-behind like this:

```
public partial class DownloadsPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly DownloadsViewModel _viewModel;

    public DownloadsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = _viewModel = new DownloadsViewModel();

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _viewModel.RefreshDownloads());
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

The bound `DownloadsViewModel`:

```
public class DownloadsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DownloadViewModel> Downloads { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DownloadViewModel>();
 
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

    public DownloadsViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Downloads";
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(() => {
            IsBusy = true;
            Downloads.Clear();
            RefreshDownloads();
            IsBusy = false;
        });
    }

    public void RefreshDownloads()
    {
        foreach (var download in DownloadManager.GetDownloads())
        {
            var existingDownload = Downloads.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == download.Id);

            if (existingDownload != null)
            {
                existingDownload.UpdateValues(download);
            }
            else
            {
                Downloads.Add(new DownloadViewModel(download));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the `ObservableCollection` contains `DownloadViewModel` that looks like this:

```
public class DownloadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IDownload _download;
    public DownloadViewModel(IDownload download)
    {
        UpdateValues(download);
    }

    private string _id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private DownloadStatus _status;
    public DownloadStatus DownloadStatus
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _status, value); }
    }

    public double PercentDownloaded
    {
        get
        {
            return _download.DownloadedBytes == -1
                ? 0f
                : (double)_download.DownloadedBytes / _download.TotalBytes;
        }
    }

    public string PercentString { get => $"{(int)(PercentDownloaded * 100)} %"; }

    public void UpdateValues(IDownload download)
    {
        _download = download;
        Id = _download.Id;
        Name = _download.Name;
        DownloadStatus = _download.Status;
    }
}
```

The error I sometimes get which causes items in my ListView to be empty:

```
Binding: 'DownloadStatus' property not found on 'Downloader.ViewModels.DownloadsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.BackgroundColor'
Binding: 'Name' property not found on 'Downloader.ViewModels.DownloadsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
Binding: 'PercentDownloaded' property not found on 'Downloader.ViewModels.DownloadsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar.Progress'
Binding: 'PercentString' property not found on 'Downloader.ViewModels.DownloadsViewModel', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
```

[image: Ghost item seen when hovering]

When debugging I've confirmed that the item is added to my ObservableCollection as expcted.

How come sometimes it's looking for DownloadStatus, Name, PercentDownloaded and PercentString on DownloadsViewModel instead of DownloadViewModel?

Comment: Could you share how do you set page `BindingContext`?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT - I edited to include how DownloadsViewModel is set as the binding context.

Comment: Your code looks correct, we can't reproduce this issue with above, could you mind share a code sample for us with onedrive or github?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Okay, I've created a cleaned up project where I'm able to reproduce it consistently, it seems to never work now. I think before when it was working was when I loaded already created downloads at startup. It doesn't work when I create a download during runtime. You can access the project here: https://github.com/OrderlyFashion/Downloader/

Comment: I've already gotten off work，Could I check it tomorrow?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yeah, of course. At your convenience. I'm happy with all the help I can get. 

Comment: I have replied answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin UWP seems to bind to the wrong view model

I checked your code sample and it works as expect. But I found the progress value does not update automatically that cause the listview item can't display, I have update the IDownload interface add PercentDownloaded property. For the testing it could works in uwp platform.

The problem was that the ViewModels did not have setters with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented for all properties. The source code is available [on Github](https://github.com/OrderlyFashion/Downloader), and the commit that fixes the issue is [this one](https://github.com/OrderlyFashion/Downloader/commit/a19db0d0bdea9cea972ad673f9846365d5b6c6fa).

Comment: If you have received above project, please tell us, for secure reason we need delete  timely.

Comment: I have downloaded the code and will take a look at it later. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, Please let me know the testing result.

Comment: Your fix works. Thanks! I'm not sure I understand exactly what the issue was though. Just make sure to always use setters with INotifyPropertyChanged for all properties in the ViewModel? The error message is definitely confusing for me at least.

Comment: Because you have bind the those bind property need to be update value , so you need implement INotifyPropertyChanged  for them. That could make sure ui will update when the property value changed, and if the answer is helpful please consider mark it. thanks.

Comment: Of course. I just think in the spirit of StackOverflow we should make clear what the actual fix is. So I've pushed your change to Github, I guess I'll leave the project up. And I'll edit your answer to make that clear.

Comment: Cool, go ahead!